# Sorting the nodes of a jQuery TreeTable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am using the jQuery [TreeTable](http://ludo.cubicphuse.nl/jquery-plugins/treeTable/doc/) plugin to display a tree of tabular data, which works really nice. Using jQuery UI's draggable & droppable allows to drop nodes onto parent nodes, just as in the [example](http://ludo.cubicphuse.nl/jquery-plugins/treeTable/doc/#example-1) of TreeTable. This uses TreeTable's `appendBranchTo` method.

This all works really nice, except that it doesn't allow sorting of the items. Sorting individual items should (I hope) be relatively easy, since this just means reordering some `tr` elements. However, I do not know how to do this for items/folders that contain other items: all the children would need to be moved too.

What would be the best way to achieve this behavior, or has anyone else done this before? Using a different plugin (that also allows reordering) for the treeview is fine too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question: I was not able to get this working with TreeTable. I ended up using  [nestedSortable](http://mjsarfatti.com/sandbox/nestedSortable/), and used some CSS to fake a table layout inside the `<li>` elements